# Dynamic Paint - "Use Object material" for Brush removed in Blender 2.8?

Tags: vertex-colors, dynamic-paint

Blender 2.79 has the option to use the material color as the brush.
Did 2.8 remove this option? Has it something to do with Blenders internal render getting removed or what's the reason?

My goal is to transfer vertex colors from one object to another, where their volumes overlap.
Transfer mesh data->Vertex Colors didn't work as cleanly as I had hoped, no matter which face corner mapping I chose.
Dynamic paint does what I want, but I can only select one color per brush object with ["Dynamic Paint"].brush_settings.paint_color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't use the material color, but used a small script to assign the vertex color of each object to the brush color of a dynmaic paint modifier. (Use Strg+L to link modifier to all objects)

```
for obj in bpy.context.collection: #use active collection
    obj_col = list(obj.data.vertex_colors['Col'].data[0].color)[:3]   
    obj.modifiers['Dynamic Paint'].brush_settings.paint_color = obj_col
```